# Custom String Format

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

I need to format boolean as string for multilanguage support "Ja"/"Nein". What is the right format string that I need for DisplayFormat and EditFormat?
I am using DevExpress with repositoryItemTextEdit as column editor in design but I think it's the same with any other binding string format. Is there another approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should definitely extract literal values "Ja"/"Nein" into localization resources. **Laoujin** makes a great response, but I will expand it a little bit with examples.

First, define custom format provider, that will use localization in some sort

```
public class LocalizedBoolFormatter : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        bool value = (bool)arg;
        format = (format == null ? null : format.Trim().ToLower());

        switch (format)
        {
            case "yn":
                return GetLocalizedBool(value);
            default:
                return HandleDefaultFormat(arg, format, formatProvider);
        }
    }

    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
            return this;
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Private methods for `LocalizedBoolFormatter`  could look like:

```
private string HandleDefaultFormat(object value, string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
{
    if (value is IFormattable)
        return ((IFormattable)value).ToString(format, formatProvider);
    else
        return value.ToString();
}

private string GetLocalizedBool(bool value)
{
    //extract from localization resources  
    //or use CultureInfo.CurrentCulture for poors man localization 
    return value ? "Ja" : "Nein";
}
```

Then you can simply format value using custom formater, which would be localized by a formatter

```
bool f = false;
string formatted = string.Format(new LocalizedBoolFormatter(), "{0:yn}", f);
Console.WriteLine (formatted);
```

With DevExpress [RepositoryItemTextEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemTextEdittopic) you can use the [Custom Formatting](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2142) as follows:

```
repositoryItemTextEdit.DisplayFormat.Format = new LocalizedBoolFormatter();
repositoryItemTextEdit.DisplayFormat.FormatType = FormatType.Custom;
```

Answer (score 3):

Boolean value cannot be translated to the current locale automatically. You could use an extension method to translate them:

```
public static string ToPrettyString(this bool value) {
    return value ? YourResource.TrueValue : YourResource.FalseValue;
}
```

If you need more flexibility, check the answer [Boolean Format String - Yes/No instead of True/False](http://forums.asp.net/t/1127044.aspx/3/10) where there is also an example of implementing `IFormatProvider`.

Answer (score 1):

The easyest way is to use a different property or column for the formated value.
You can also use the Parse/Format events of the data binding:

```
repositoryItemTextEdit1.DataBindings[0].Format += new ConvertEventHandler(repositoryItemTextEdit1_Format);

repositoryItemTextEdit1.DataBindings[0].Parse += new ConvertEventHandler(repositoryItemTextEdit1_Parse);

void repositoryItemTextEdit1_Format(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
{
   return e.Value ? "Ja" : "Nein";
}

void repositoryItemTextEdit1_Parse(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
{
   return e.Value.Equals("Ja") ? yes : no;
}
```